# Gorilla websockets, multiple messages in one event

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am using the chat app example from gorilla websockets, but I have an issue, sometimes, when the backend needs to send two different messages to the client, they are send in just one Message Event, this is bad for me because JSON.parse will fail parsing 2 jsons from one string.
I can do a split by newline and get every json from the message, but I prefer not to.
If I put a timeout on backend everything works.
Can I do something to prevent this? If not can you please explain me why?

This is the chat example:
https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

This is my code where I broadcast 2 messages:

```
if err == nil {
    c.SendMessageWithOrders(DB)
    data := models.EventSuccess{
        Event: utils.EventOrdersCreateSuccess,
    }
    toReturnBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err == nil {
    toReturn := BroadcastOne{
        ID:      c.ID,
        Message: toReturnBytes,
    }
    NewHub.broadcastOne <- &toReturn
    }
}
```

`c.SendMessageWithOrders(DB)` Is making `NewHub.broadcastOne <- &toReturn` with different data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code in [client.go](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/c3e18be99d19e6b3e8f1559eea2c161a665c4b6b/examples/chat/client.go#L104-L109) reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending queued chat messages as a single WebSocket message:

```
        n := len(c.send)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            w.Write(newline)
            w.Write(<-c.send)
        }
```

Fix the problem by deleting the code from the example.  The optimization is not required.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me please, why this optimization was added, I want to know what was the thought behind this code

Comment: @jalanga The optimization reduces overhead from WebSocket frame headers, TCP segment headers, etc.

Comment: `w.Write` does not send the data immediately? Then when is the data sent? `w.Write` just accumulates the data into some buffer, and `w.Close()` is the one who really sends the accumulated data?

Comment: @starriet The message writer buffers output to reduce the number of frame headers and system calls.  Close the message writer to flush any data remaining in the buffer.

Comment: @BaytaDarell Thank you! So... is my previous comment correct? (w.Write accumulates the data to the buffer, and w.Close flush the buffer by sending the whole accumulated data) 
Just want to make sure if I understood correctly :)

Comment: @starriet  The application specifies the write buffer size. The write buffer is written to the network when the buffer fills and when the writer is closed.  An entire message is accumulated in memory only when the message size is less than the buffer size.